# How can I comment a line using thor from a Rails 3 Template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thor

I want to comment a line from a file (`spec_helper.rb`) using [thor](http://textmate.rubyforge.org/thor/Thor/Actions.html) in my Rails 3 template?

from:

```
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
```

to

```
# config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
```

I know I can inject a line to a file using `inject_into_file`, but I would like to comment a line from the specified file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but I had the same today...

Now you can use directly the function comment_lines, please see the github source code and comment here: https://github.com/rails/thor/blob/main/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb

[Github source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pein.png)

If needed the reverse action "uncomment" is available too.

Both of these functions use gsub_file as the first answer sugested.

In my use case, I comment the flag "database:" with in the "config/database.yml" file with this command:

```
comment_lines 'config/database.yml', /database:/
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Thor Action gsub_file

Example from the documentation

```
gsub_file 'app/controllers/application_controller.rb', /#\s*(filter_parameter_logging :password)/, '\1'
```

You have to adapt the regex and replacement string on your needs, but this should be possible.